# GitHub scenarios for website development and deployment

Tags: git, web, github, deployment, devops

How can I publish changed files on a GitHub server, when the files changes are in a different path than the git repo?

Well, this is the current scenario:

**DEVELOPMENT** server:

Synched with github:

```
/development/web   #html,js, etc...
```

Not linked directly to github:

```
/www/web (Same html files. Apache is looking at here)
```

I would like to:

```
1. Do changes in www/web files (to test the results locally)
2. Propagate these changes in /development/web 
3. Commit&Push changes to github
```

- Is it possible to do this with symlinks?
- Client side hooks? I don't think they will work as long as the hooks live in the git repo.

Comment: Sorry, we're not here for "ideas". We're here to answer concrete programming questions. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is far too broad and far too opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question. Hopefully someone has done something similar and can help. I found other people was trying to do a similar thing, so it is not a bad question.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to develop right in `/www/web` on your server? Why not run a local development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the workflow works the other way:

- you modify, add, commit and push files in a dedicated folder of your Git repository.
- a post-receive server hook on your server extract the right folder of your Git repository to /www/web

Doing modification directly on the server might work through symlink (if `/www/web` is linked to `/your/repo/web`), meaning your Git repository does not have symlink, but the deployment environment does, and link back to the repository.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am finally doing. I.e. my www/web contains all the symlinks to the development .git folder in my development machine.
For the server side, I haven't tried yet, but the same approach is valid. So when I pull the changes from GitHub it will update server files. Probably a server hook will also work, but sounds more complex and probably the links is enough.